# EF Code-First - Mapping stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm trying to implement nested sets in my database model. To make it easy to use I would like to create stored procedures for insert/update/delete operations on my tree nodes to keep my tree in a valid state.

Is it possible to create mapping of the stored procedures in the current version of code-first model? I mean that my stored procedures will be called when for example, new entity will be added to the dbcontext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Code First in Entity Framework does not support Stored Procedure by
>   default. As there is no designer we cannot even map our stored procs
>   to the entity. There are a many scenario we have seen where we are
>   bound to use stored procedure for any database modifications
>   (insert/update/delete).

You can use below links, and/or google your question to find more solutions.

[Using Entity Framework Code First with Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/09/23/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-stored-procedures-that-have-output-parameters.aspx) AND [Code First 4.1 : Using Stored Procedure to Insert Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-4-1-using-stored-procedure-to-insert-data.aspx)