# How to query a stored procedure object with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Say I got this situation: I have to filter one of my entities with data which I get from an stored procedure:

```
var results = from c in db.Customer
join p in db.GetSPResults() on c.Id equals p.Id
select c;
```

on my Context class I got this:

```
public ObjectResult<Example> GetSPResults()
{
    return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Example>("Proc_Example");
}
```

So far I run into 2 problems:

1. I get an InvalidOperationException when code strikes the ExcecuteFunction line:

   > *The FunctionImport 'xxx' could not be found in the container 'xxx'*.
2. Assuming you guys can help me to solve that problem, would it be possible to query that way? Using those stored procedure results like a context entity? I think EF won't allow that cause it's not an entity, nor a "Constant Value".

I'm using EF 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of calling your procedure like that by name as string you can import it in your entity model then you can have a type safe / strongly typed method call directly on your DbContext.

basically you need to execute a function import, see here for an example: [Using stored procedures with Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/01/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx)

Update: for POCO / Code first, see here: [EF Code-First - Mapping stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664449/ef-code-first-mapping-stored-procedures)

Comment: I'm using POCO. Model creates the Database, but do you know if is it possible to define an stored procedure or a view using POCO?

Comment: Thanks! But I've already tried that, the results of `SqlQuery` method won't work for querying (due to the reason I name on item 2, it's not an entity or a constant value). Any other idea?

Comment: ok I've did it returning just an id list from the Stored procedure. That way linq understands it to query just fine. Thanks I'll post the answer.